# angular ui-router skip login for authenticated user

Tags: angularjs, authentication, cookies, routes, angular-ui-router

i have an angularjs app, i am using cookie based authentication in this app. when i login with two different users in same browser window in different tabs my cookie gets override. For example i am logged in with a user 'A' in first tab of browser and i am logged in with a user 'B' in second tab of the same browser window. when i check the cookie in browser, i only see the information about last logged in user. and when i try to navigate through application with user 'A' i get wrong data. 
my question is is there any way i can skip login screen if a user is already logged in my application? so that no other user can login within same browser?
i tried to use `resolve:`in `AngularApp.config` and tried to redirect already logged in user to `/home` but still i am unable to achieve it. any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Once the login is completed you can save the status of the application in session storage. Then when you are initialising the application you can check the value exits in session storage or not and redirect user to different page depend on the value. Make sure you are removing the stored value in session storage when user logout from the application